# Mathmatica saving Matlab files as Mathmatica as Wolfram Mathmatica Package

Tags: matlab

I have used Matlab for years and had to download Mathmatica for a class. However when I saved a Matlab file I think I accidently gave Mathmatica permission to be the defualt for .m files.I have changed the defaulf back to Matlab but all my .m files are still listed as Wolfram Mathmatica Package files. I would just like to know how to convert the files back to Matlab .m files.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is not really a programming-related question, and is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. You can find a tutorial online on how to change the default program for the `.m` file type for your operating system. (Windows: https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-default-program-to-open-a-file-with/)

Comment: Note that your files haven't changed, it is just Windows putting the wrong icon next to them because `.m` is registered as Mathematica. Double-clicking on the file might not work, but you can still open and use the files in MATLAB in all other ways: type `edit myfile` in MATLAB, use the File->Open menu, etc.